# for each looping getting out of scope exception MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

am facing a strange issue.

Am looping a list object. The list contain 18 object. The loop running 18 times but the end of the 18th one getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**.

```
      @For Each Slogs As SFAMobile.MobileServices.CustomerDetail In Model.Customers  
           @<option value='@Slogs.CustomerId' @selectedVal >@Slogs.Name ( @Slogs.CustomerId ) </option>
      Next
```

please help me to fix this issue

Thanks in Advance 
Ramesh R C

Comment: As suggested, use Html.DropDownListFor helper

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the `Model.Customers` collection doesn't contain null elements. By the way in order to generate a dropdown list you might consider using the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper instead of writing loops and stuff.

Comment: Model.Customers d't have null value. Yes i can use Html.DropDownListFor but the drop down value is combination of two field that's y i given loop to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are using "As SFAMobile.MobileServices.CustomerDetail" to cast each element in Model.Customers - if the 18th item in Model.Customers cannot be casted to that then "Slogs" will be null for that iteration.

Comment: Yes i removed still am getting same error , right now my code is like

Comment: For Each Slogs In Model.Customers
<option value='@Slogs.CustomerId' selectedVal >Slogs.Name ( Slogs.CustomerId ) </option>
                    Next"